# SQL server management connection

Tags: sql-server, netbeans

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZqFt.jpg My question is about why i can't find sql express in the configuration management and any tips on connecting sql server databases to netbean. I'm currently using microsoft sql server management 2017 enterprise . Many thanks :)

Comment: Why do you think that there should be **Express **instance? You have full edition installed on this pc that is definitely not Express (you have also SSIS and Analysis Services installed)

Comment: So basically with sql enterprise there will be no express instance in it because enterprise edition is full edition ?

Comment: You can install up to 50 instances on  one physical server. So you can have Enterprise + Expresss but why do you want Express? there is nothing that exists in Express and does not exist in Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

You've alredy found your instance (that is `default instance`), that's correct that you see PC name as server name, only in case of `named instance` you should write it's name like `my_pc\my_server_name`, in your case it's `pc` name only.

Just click `connect` button and if this login exists on server your connection will succeed.

Comment: Many thanks man. One more question, what is sql server authentication for ? To connect sql server via online ?

Comment: SQL Server is **secured**. If someone knows instance name and has acces to pc it still cannot rerach the server if DBA did not create a login for this person. So if your windows account exists as a login on that server you can connect using Windows authentication